# ndiff not found in nmap 7.7 package in centOS 8

Tags: centos, centos7, nmap, centos8

I just installed centOS8 and then the nmap package.
and I cannot find the ndiff binary.
Weird, I could find it in nmap in centOS7

Anyone having the same problem? Thanks
Ester

Comment: I downloaded the sources and compiled nmap-7.80.tar.bz2  from scratch and ndiff is there....

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `ndiff` is not a binary, but a Python 2 script. Due to the deprecation of Python 2 in Fedora and RHEL (and thus in CentOS), `ndiff` is no longer shipped in current versions of Fedora and RHEL/CentOS. See https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/nmap/blob/master/f/nmap.spec#_157 regarding the removal.

Comment: Thanks!  I hope tbey release it with python 3 though.  Useful script